# Why does this php code not work if ((a==a and b==b) or (c==c)) {}

Tags: php

I can't find why and/or in one line of if doesn't work
it gets a=a and b=b that works but it wont get c=c that doesn't work

Example:

```
if ((a==a and b==b) or (c==c)) {}
```

Actual code:

```
 if (($_POST['name'] == $naam and $_POST['password'] == $wachtwoord) or ($loggedin == 1)) {
```

Comment: What are the values of all those variables? Right now, it looks fine.

Comment: Please update your example with `==` `=` is the assignment operator. `==` is the equality check operator.

Comment: @Marc What if the problem you fixed was *the* problem?

Answer (score 2):

`($_POST['name'] == $naam and $_POST['password'] == $wachtwoord` is true if the username and password match. `($loggedin == 1)` is true if the user is logged in. The combination of these roughly means "is this a valid user?", where a valid user either provided their credentials with this request or was already verified to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Problem was not that part of the code but using an elseif with an !isset for a $_post.
So now only it would go to the elseif if there was a $_post and would always ignore the or whatever I put there. It really made it seem like or didn't work stupid I'm ashamed.

Thank you all tough for the fast responses, and I didn't know about var_dump yet so thanks for that.